# Async methods which are marked as “ExcludeFromCodeCoverage” still shown as not covered in Sonarqube

Tags: c#, async-await, sonarqube, code-coverage

I have a Windows service which has few async methods in it.
I'm writing unit test cases for all these methods. For one async method, I do not want to write any test cases, so I have decorated that method with `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]`.

I'm using Sonarqube to check the code coverage.
What I observed are async methods which has `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]`

```
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
async Task IEventProcessor.CloseAsync(PartitionContext context, CloseReason reason) { 
    if (reason == CloseReason.Shutdown) {
        await context.CheckpointAsync();
    }
}
```

are still showing as not covered in the sonarqube tool.

But when I refactored my code to remove *async* from the method,

```
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
Task IEventProcessor.CloseAsync(PartitionContext context, CloseReason reason)  
    if (reason == CloseReason.Shutdown) {
        return context.CheckpointAsync();
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

it is working fine as expected.

So wanted to know, why sonarqube is not considering async methods.

Is there any setting or configuration to do done which I might me missing?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Professional, framework : 4.6.1, SonarQube - 7.1 , if it helps.

Comment: Have a read of this article. Apparently there are issues with *async/await* and code coverage. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dwayneneed/2014/11/17/code-coverage-with-async-await/

Comment: I would also suggest you update the question with code that demonstrates the issue as some may not visualize the explanation you gave for *async methods*